# OS X - app can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed when bundle includes new version of third-party executable

Tags: objective-c, macos, code-signing

I have an app which has a third-party executable in its bundle resources. I used to sign the app during release phase and distribute outside of Mac App Store. All is fine. After I have updated the third-party executable, once app is signed as usual and downloaded from website to mac, OS X shows alert "app can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed".

I tried signing third-party executable before signing an app: didn't make a difference.
If I replace new third-party executable with an old version (resign and redownload) - app warning is not showing and everything is fine.

"codesign -dv app" shows reasonable identical output for signed app bundle with old or new version of a third-party executable.

App is signed with a valid Mac Developer Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if all the binaries in your bundle are not referring to libs outside of /usr/bin or /System.
In our case we had one with an absolute path and GateKeeper would not allow it to be run. codesign --verify was useless.

You can use the following command:
otool -L path_to_binary

If you see any dependency outside of /System or /usr/bin - get rid of them